# Reputation section of FAQ does not mention viewing of edit queue as a privilege at 5000 reputation

Tags: support, faq-update-request

The [current description of reputation in the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) doesn't list 5000 as the point users can see the edit queue.

This should probably be addressed. Are there any other missing milestones?